# What is currently the best, free time picker for WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, datetimepicker, timepicker

I'm looking for a simple **time picker** control for WPF.

- I've found this one:

http://marlongrech.wordpress.com/2007/11/18/time-picker/

but it has some **issues** e.g. you can't type in "00" into it, the second zero won't appear.

- Silverlight seems to have one:

http://jesseliberty.com/2009/03/28/toolkit-control-%E2%80%93-timepicker/

but it's **not for WPF**.

- The WPF Toolkit has a DatePicker but not a TimePicker by itself. Or is there a way to allow the user to enter time and date in the WPFToolkit DatePicker? It *returns* a DateTime in SelectedDate but I don't see how to allow the user to also choose the time with this control.

**What is the best free WPF control to allow users enter time in HH:MM:SS format?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can roll your own pretty easily as shown [here](https://jobijoy.blogspot.com/2007/10/time-picker-user-control.html).  And that way, you can get exactly what you want.

Comment: This is quite a nice example, I just it would take keyboard and mouse input without changing the code. :-)

Comment: the time picker is terrible

Answer (score 22):

I like the controls from the extended WPF toolkit: [Link to source code on github](https://github.com/xceedsoftware/wpftoolkit)

In the package, the [DateTimeUpDown](https://github.com/xceedsoftware/wpftoolkit/wiki/DateTimeUpDown) is contained which can be used for your purpose. If you don't want to use the `Date` part of it, you can set the `Format` to "ShortTime" or whatever format you wanna have.

Hope that helps.

Comment: I have to regret ... I don't know why but they use a DateTime? for the value of the TimePicker ... that does not fit with my model. Probably I could do things to fix that but I prefer to go to another control.

Comment: They do that so that when you bind to a database table column, the control does not have a fit when that column contains nulls, as they often do. If your model does not consider this scenario then perhaps it needs more thought.

Comment: A word of warning: the linked WPF toolkit is free _for non-commercial use only_.

Comment: _Extended WPF Toolkit_ also does not support .NET 6 (Core) in the free version.

Answer (score 10):

I could't find one on the web, so I created it from scratch. I don't completely understand Dependency Properties, so i'm omitted those for now. The control is a 12 hour time picker control. I'm new to WPF so I don't fully understand all the new language syntaxes but this control will do the trick for me in the project i'm creating at home.

It supports setting time as a DateTime or a TimeSpan.

Below I will paste the XAML and the Code-Behind.
The XAML

```
<UserControl x:Class="WorkDayManager3.WPF.UserControls.TimeControl"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="35" d:DesignWidth="100">
    <Border BorderBrush="LightBlue" BorderThickness="1" Margin="1">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="5" />
                <ColumnDefinition />
                <ColumnDefinition />
                <ColumnDefinition />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <TextBox x:Name="txtHours" BorderThickness="0" MaxLength="2" TextAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="1" KeyUp="txt_KeyUp" MouseWheel="txt_MouseWheel" PreviewKeyUp="txt_PreviewKeyUp" />
            <TextBlock Text=":" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
            <TextBox x:Name="txtMinutes" BorderThickness="0" MaxLength="2" TextAlignment="Center" Grid.Column="2" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="00" KeyUp="txt_KeyUp" MouseWheel="txt_MouseWheel" PreviewKeyUp="txt_PreviewKeyUp" />
            <TextBox x:Name="txtAmPm" BorderThickness="0" MaxLength="2" TextAlignment="Center" Grid.Column="3" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" PreviewTextInput="txtAmPm_PreviewTextInput" Text="AM" KeyUp="txt_KeyUp" MouseWheel="txt_MouseWheel" Padding="0, 0, 3, 0" />
            <Grid Grid.Column="4">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition />
                    <RowDefinition />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Button x:Name="btnUp" Focusable="False" Click="btnUp_Click">
                    <TextBlock Text="p" FontFamily="Wingdings 3" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                </Button>
                <Button x:Name="btnDown" Grid.Row="1" Focusable="False" Click="btnDown_Click">
                    <TextBlock Text="q" FontFamily="Wingdings 3" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                </Button>
            </Grid>
        </Grid>
    </Border>
</UserControl>
```

The Code-Behind

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Input;

namespace WorkDayManager3.WPF.UserControls
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for TimeControl.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class TimeControl : UserControl
    {
        public TimeControl()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        #region Properties

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets the date time value.
        /// </summary>
        /// <value>The date time value.</value>
        public DateTime? DateTimeValue
        {
            get
            {
                string hours = this.txtHours.Text;
                string minutes = this.txtMinutes.Text;
                string amPm = this.txtAmPm.Text;
                if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(hours)
                    && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(minutes)
                    && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(amPm))
                {
                    string value = string.Format("{0}:{1} {2}", this.txtHours.Text, this.txtMinutes.Text, this.txtAmPm.Text);
                    DateTime time = DateTime.Parse(value);
                    return time;
                }
                else
                {
                    return null;
                }
            }
            set
            {
                DateTime? time = value;
                if (time.HasValue)
                {
                    string timeString = time.Value.ToShortTimeString();
                    //9:54 AM
                    string[] values = timeString.Split(':', ' ');
                    if (values.Length == 3)
                    {
                        this.txtHours.Text = values[0];
                        this.txtMinutes.Text = values[1];
                        this.txtAmPm.Text = values[2];
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets the time span value.
        /// </summary>
        /// <value>The time span value.</value>
        public TimeSpan? TimeSpanValue
        {
            get
            {
                DateTime? time = this.DateTimeValue;
                if (time.HasValue)
                {
                    return new TimeSpan(time.Value.Ticks);
                }
                else
                {
                    return null;
                }
            }
            set
            {
                TimeSpan? timeSpan = value;
                if (timeSpan.HasValue)
                {
                    this.DateTimeValue = new DateTime(timeSpan.Value.Ticks);
                }
            }
        }

        #endregion

        #region Event Subscriptions

        /// <summary>
        /// Handles the Click event of the btnDown control.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="sender">The source of the event.</param>
        /// <param name="e">The <see cref="System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs"/> instance containing the event data.</param>
        private void btnDown_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            string controlId = this.GetControlWithFocus().Name;
            if ("txtHours".Equals(controlId))
            {
                this.ChangeHours(false);
            }
            else if ("txtMinutes".Equals(controlId))
            {
                this.ChangeMinutes(false);
            }
            else if ("txtAmPm".Equals(controlId))
            {
                this.ToggleAmPm();
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Handles the Click event of the btnUp control.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="sender">The source of the event.</param>
        /// <param name="e">The <see cref="System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs"/> instance containing the event data.</param>
        private void btnUp_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            string controlId = this.GetControlWithFocus().Name;
            if ("txtHours".Equals(controlId))
            {
                this.ChangeHours(true);
            }
            else if ("txtMinutes".Equals(controlId))
            {
                this.ChangeMinutes(true);
            }
            else if ("txtAmPm".Equals(controlId))
            {
                this.ToggleAmPm();
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Handles the PreviewTextInput event of the txtAmPm control.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="sender">The source of the event.</param>
        /// <param name="e">The <see cref="System.Windows.Input.TextCompositionEventArgs"/> instance containing the event data.</param>
        private void txtAmPm_PreviewTextInput(object sender, TextCompositionEventArgs e)
        {
            // prevent users to type text
            e.Handled = true;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Handles the KeyUp event of the txt control.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="sender">The source of the event.</param>
        /// <param name="e">The <see cref="System.Windows.Input.KeyEventArgs"/> instance containing the event data.</param>
        private void txt_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            // check for up and down keyboard presses
            if (Key.Up.Equals(e.Key))
            {
                btnUp_Click(this, null);
            }
            else if (Key.Down.Equals(e.Key))
            {
                btnDown_Click(this, null);
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Handles the MouseWheel event of the txt control.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="sender">The source of the event.</param>
        /// <param name="e">The <see cref="System.Windows.Input.MouseWheelEventArgs"/> instance containing the event data.</param>
        private void txt_MouseWheel(object sender, MouseWheelEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Delta > 0)
            {
                btnUp_Click(this, null);
            }
            else
            {
                btnDown_Click(this, null);
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Handles the PreviewKeyUp event of the txt control.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="sender">The source of the event.</param>
        /// <param name="e">The <see cref="System.Windows.Input.KeyEventArgs"/> instance containing the event data.</param>
        private void txt_PreviewKeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            TextBox textBox = (TextBox)sender;
            // make sure all characters are number
            bool allNumbers = textBox.Text.All(Char.IsNumber);
            if (!allNumbers)
            {
                e.Handled = true;
                return;
            }


            // make sure user did not enter values out of range
            int value;
            int.TryParse(textBox.Text, out value);
            if ("txtHours".Equals(textBox.Name) && value > 12)
            {
                EnforceLimits(e, textBox);
            }
            else if ("txtMinutes".Equals(textBox.Name) && value > 59)
            {
                EnforceLimits(e, textBox);
            }
        }

        #endregion

        #region Methods

        /// <summary>
        /// Changes the hours.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="isUp">if set to <c>true</c> [is up].</param>
        private void ChangeHours(bool isUp)
        {
            int value = Convert.ToInt32(this.txtHours.Text);
            if (isUp)
            {
                value += 1;
                if (value == 13)
                {
                    value = 1;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                value -= 1;
                if (value == 0)
                {
                    value = 12;
                }
            }
            this.txtHours.Text = Convert.ToString(value);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Changes the minutes.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="isUp">if set to <c>true</c> [is up].</param>
        private void ChangeMinutes(bool isUp)
        {
            int value = Convert.ToInt32(this.txtMinutes.Text);
            if (isUp)
            {
                value += 1;
                if (value == 60)
                {
                    value = 0;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                value -= 1;
                if (value == -1)
                {
                    value = 59;
                }
            }

            string textValue = Convert.ToString(value);
            if (value < 10)
            {
                textValue = "0" + Convert.ToString(value);
            }
            this.txtMinutes.Text = textValue;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Enforces the limits.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="e">The <see cref="System.Windows.Input.KeyEventArgs"/> instance containing the event data.</param>
        /// <param name="textBox">The text box.</param>
        /// <param name="enteredValue">The entered value.</param>
        private static void EnforceLimits(KeyEventArgs e, TextBox textBox)
        {
            string enteredValue = GetEnteredValue(e.Key);
            string text = textBox.Text.Replace(enteredValue, "");
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(text))
            {
                text = enteredValue;
            }
            textBox.Text = text;
            e.Handled = true;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets the control with focus.
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns></returns>
        private TextBox GetControlWithFocus()
        {
            TextBox txt = new TextBox();
            if (this.txtHours.IsFocused)
            {
                txt = this.txtHours;
            }
            else if (this.txtMinutes.IsFocused)
            {
                txt = this.txtMinutes;
            }
            else if (this.txtAmPm.IsFocused)
            {
                txt = this.txtAmPm;
            }
            return txt;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets the entered value.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="key">The key.</param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        private static string GetEnteredValue(Key key)
        {
            string value = string.Empty;
            switch (key)
            {
                case Key.D0:
                case Key.NumPad0:
                    value = "0";
                    break;
                case Key.D1:
                case Key.NumPad1:
                    value = "1";
                    break;
                case Key.D2:
                case Key.NumPad2:
                    value = "2";
                    break;
                case Key.D3:
                case Key.NumPad3:
                    value = "3";
                    break;
                case Key.D4:
                case Key.NumPad4:
                    value = "4";
                    break;
                case Key.D5:
                case Key.NumPad5:
                    value = "5";
                    break;
                case Key.D6:
                case Key.NumPad6:
                    value = "6";
                    break;
                case Key.D7:
                case Key.NumPad7:
                    value = "7";
                    break;
                case Key.D8:
                case Key.NumPad8:
                    value = "8";
                    break;
                case Key.D9:
                case Key.NumPad9:
                    value = "9";
                    break;
            }
            return value;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Toggles the am pm.
        /// </summary>
        private void ToggleAmPm()
        {
            if ("AM".Equals(this.txtAmPm.Text))
            {
                this.txtAmPm.Text = "PM";
            }
            else
            {
                this.txtAmPm.Text = "AM";
            }
        }

        #endregion
    }
}
```

That's the control, feel free to make modifications as needed. It's not perfect but it's better than other controls i've found

Answer (score 0):

The [MahApps library](http://mahapps.com/) has a Timepicker control since version 1.3.0.