# New DateTimePicker for WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls, datetimepicker

Are there newer, and better **DateTimePicker** out there that can resemble more of Window's default **DateTimePicker** for WPF C#?

[image]

Yes, I know this is not a new question. 
There are [WPF Toolkits](http://wpf.codeplex.com/releases/view/22567) and [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1833357/what-is-currently-the-best-free-time-picker-for-wpf). But these are fairly dated (latest update I found were from the 09) and I am not able to find any newer sources. There is this [Avalon Library](http://marlongrech.wordpress.com/2008/02/06/wpf-date-time-picker/) but, no offense, it's buggy, ugly and difficult to implement (for me perhaps), also difficult to click the textboxes etc.

Are there newer, open source or commercial DateTimePicker? Do people host their DateTimePicker Form Control in WPF?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The clock in the image is not part of the time control. It is just a clock.

You could have a look at [the commercial controls of Telerik](http://www.telerik.com/products/wpf/datetimepicker.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Note that what you are showing is most likely not a single control but a combination of controls. In there I see a month calendar control, a time picker and a custom control showing an analogic clock.

bout WPF controls there are tons of libraries and suites out there with anything you need including datetime and time pickers, for example Telerik, Infragistic, DevExpress etc...