# TimeSpan Control for WPF

Tags: wpf, timespan

Is there a good Timespan contorl for WPF? I'm looking for one that looks like the Timepicker from WPF Toolkit extended (small and compact). The examples I've seen from codeproject are too bulky for my UI. If not I would be willing to create one myself and would like advice. Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is currently the best, free time picker for WPF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1833357/what-is-currently-the-best-free-time-picker-for-wpf)

Comment: Why not using the one on WPF Toolkit extended? Since there is no native one, any other would be just as good as the WPF Toolkit extended one.

Comment: @nvoigt `TimeSpan` is not the same thing as a Time -- a `TimeSpan` represents the length of a span of time, such as "5 minutes and 8 seconds" -- not a time of day, such as "3:00 PM".

Comment: Also WPF Toolkit extended isn't free anymore for commercial use. And sometimes its a real pain to get some money from your boss even for the smallest investments. So an alternative is always welcome ;)