# Set value to one property thru a range of fixed buttons or a custom value

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, radio-button, converters

I have one property in my model which stores time in seconds. On UI, I have to display options thru radio buttons with 1,5,10,15,30 min and 1 hr options along with a custom value radio button with minute and hour option in combobox.

On selecting custom value, the value in the text box and combo box with minuter and hour as options I set the interval in my model.
For the rest I am using converter and its parameter to set the value. It is as follows:

```
 public class SamplingIntervalConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        static  int[] secondsArray = new int[]{60,300,600,900,1800,3600};
        object IValueConverter.Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            int dataSeconds = 0;
            int parameterSeconds = 0;
            if (int.TryParse(value.ToString(), out dataSeconds))
            {
                if(int.TryParse(parameter.ToString(),out parameterSeconds))
                {
                    if (dataSeconds == parameterSeconds)
                    {
                        return true;
                    }
                }
                else if (parameter.ToString().Equals("Custom") && !secondsArray.Contains(dataSeconds))
                {
                    return true;
                }
            }

            return false;
        }

        object IValueConverter.ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            if ((bool)value)
            {
                int parameterSeconds = 0;
                if (int.TryParse(parameter.ToString(), out parameterSeconds))
                {
                    return parameterSeconds;
                }
            }
            return 0;
        }
    }
```

Is there a better way of solving this problem. I would really appreciate some help on this.

Thanks :)

Comment: You could just databind an invisible textbox to your model, when you change the radio button selected, update the text of the textbox which will change your model

Answer (score 1):

If you really *have* to use all of these buttons, then either connect `Click` handlers or bind `Command` objects to them, depending on whether you use view models or not. Then in your code behind or view model, simply react to the button clicks by adding to your seconds value property.

Personally, I would display a `TimeSpan` object instead of the seconds integer because that can use a nice `StringFormat` like `{0:HH:mm}` to display the duration in a user friendly way. You could do something like this:

```
public TimeSpan Duration
{
    get { return TimeSpan.FromSeconds(LengthInSeconds); }
    set
    {
        if (TimeSpan.FromSeconds(LengthInSeconds) != value)
        {
            LengthInSeconds = (short)value.TotalSeconds;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("Duration");
        }
    }
}
```

Alternatively, take a look at the [What is currently the best, free time picker for WPF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1833357/what-is-currently-the-best-free-time-picker-for-wpf) post for controls that the users can use to select `TimeSpan` values.